# Exporting rules to ndjson generates incomplete file

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack, elk

I'm trying to export all the 722 rules into an ndjson file, but the file is incomplete. There are two sets of rule: Elastic rules and Custom rules.

I go to Security > Overview > Rules > Select all 722 rules > Bulk Actions > Export selected.

[image]

However, the resulting output contains the following, which is NOT what I need.

[image]

Now, when I select the 20 Custom rules, I do get the expect output.
[image]

Any idea on how to fix this? Or am I doing something wrong?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a solution to this.

What worked for me was to use a GET request to return all rules in json format

```
https://<IP address":<port>/api/detection_engine/rules/_find?page=1&per_page=<number of results to include>
```

All the info is here:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/security/current/rules-api-find.html

Comment: Well done ✅ glad to see it is possible

Answer (score 1):

It is an [ongoing issue](https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/50266) I think.

Comment: Looks like it. Thanks for the help, Paulo.

Comment: Found the answer!